# PrimeNG Calendar <p-calendar> - How to disable UTC - Z timezone

Tags: angular, date, primeng

Does anyone know if it's possible to disable the date/time picker from automatically adding the UTC time to the date object? As you can see in the below picture that it's automatically adjusting my date object to UTC. I want my date object submitted with 10:00:00

[image]

```
{"reportedDate": "2019-02-13T15:00:16.000Z"}


<p-calendar required [(ngModel)]="entry.reportedDate" name="reportedDate" #reportedDate="ngModel" [showIcon]="true" [showTime]="true" dateFormat="mm/dd/y 'EST'" hourFormat="24"></p-calendar>
```

Comment: It's probably just a `Date` object and in javascript when you convert a date to a string it is always in that format. Why do you want another representation? Can you eleborate on how you use that value and _why_ it is a problem?

Comment: I have multiple users using this form in different timezones and I want to use one standard timezone (EST) when submitting and reporting issues. So when users submit the forms I don't want the date object to change depending on the users browser/computer but stick strictly to the date the pick in the datepicker.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [the documentation page for this component](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar) (in the properties table):

> ```
> Name        Type      Default    Description
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
> dataType    string    date       Type of the value to write back to ngModel,
>                                  default is date and alternative is string.
> ```

You should pass `[dataType]="string"`.  This will prevent a `Date` object from being constructed, which will in-turn prevent any time zone conversions.

Also, I recommend *not* putting a time zone abbreviation in the format for the entry.  Keep in mind that daylight saving time might be in effect depending on the date chosen, and also that not every time zone has a clear and consistent abbreviation, and that some abbreviations (such as CST or IST) are ambiguous.

If you need to indicate to the user that the entry is in US Eastern Time, then put that somewhere outside of the textbox.  If you *must* use an abbreviation, use `ET` as the generic form.

Comment: Thanks Matt for this solution. I think it should be used as `<p-calendar dataType="string" ... ></p-calendar>` without [] around dataType since we don't need to evaluate "string" here.

Comment: this does not work for me, pls can u give more context

Comment: This helped me, the prime ng version is 6 and angular 6.

Answer (score 0):

Format the date to the timezone you want using the offset.

*edit
BAD EXAMPLE (DON'T DO THIS):

```
var dt = new Date(1458619200000);
console.log(dt); // Gives Tue Mar 22 2016 09:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

dt.setTime(dt.getTime()+dt.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000);
console.log(dt); // Gives Tue Mar 22 2016 04:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

var offset = -300; //Timezone offset for EST in minutes.
var estDate = new Date(dt.getTime() + offset*60*1000);
console.log(estDate); //Gives Mon Mar 21 2016 23:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

**From Experience:**
I don't know how you're storing this date. Things can quickly become complicated when you're talking about time zones. Later on when you do want to support showing different time zones. You will then have to go from Eastern to Central on your clients device. All your entries in your DB are in Eastern Time and Conversions are needed in the backend. Your servers are now hosted in a different TimeZone and you need custom logic in every service call (Nightmares!!!)

Do yourself a favor now and save everything in UTC.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but this isn't really an answer to the question that was asked.  Also, the approach described here is commonly cited, but is flawed.  1) On line 3 above, you're already working with a UTC based timestamp, so adjusting it by the local offset is incorrect. 2) On line 5 above, you're assuming that the timestamp will always need to be in EST (UTC-5), but depending on if DST is in effect, it might need to be EDT (EST-4) - which is indeed the case for the example date given.

Comment: 3) On line 6, you're again trying to adjust by an offset.  This part is called "epoch shifting", and can only be used if subsequently only the UTC-based functions on the resulting `Date` object are called.  Though India doesn't have DST, in other time zones the local time zone's DST transitions could impact the resulting value for local-time-based functions, such as the implicit string conversion being shown here.  In summary, the `Date` object *cannot* be adjusted to other time zones.

Comment: Indeed, consider your results are wrong, because 9:30 on March 22 2016 in India is actually midnight (00:00) on March 22 2016 in US Eastern Time.  [Reference here](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20160322T040000&p1=176&p2=179).

Comment: BTW, in most browsers, you can now specify a time zone as an option to `toLocaleString`, such as:  `console.log(new Date(1458619200000).toLocaleString(undefined, {timeZone: 'America/New_York'}))`.  This correctly converts the UTC timestamp to the desired time zone identifier.

Comment: @MattJohnson Indeed you're correct. Thank you for your thorough code review. I'll leave the post so that people can see the answer with you're feedback. Thanks.